# Issue in SQL Server 2008 while converting varchar to date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a `nvarchar` column and it is containing dates in different formats like

```
'2/1/2012',
'2/2/12',
'20 01 12',
'20 03 2012',
'20.01.12',
'30.04.2012',
'20jan 12',
'20-MARCH-2012',
'22MARCH2012',
'23 may 2012',
'23-MAR-2012',
'26MAR-2012',
'27TH JAN 4660',
'CHL. Date- 30.01.2012',
'APRIL/12/2012',
'N/A',
'DT.:5/1/12',
```

Now I want to insert the data from this column to date column in format `dd/mm/yyyy` but not able to do that as it always give error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Please help if anyone knows how to convert this column to date column with all specified values defined above

Comment: A `DATETIME` column in SQL Server has **no string format** associated with it. A `DATETIME` is a `DATETIME` is a `DATETIME` - it's stored as 8 binary bytes - **no formatting**. How the `DATETIME` is displayed (as a string) is a totally different story - it's dependent on the database's language and reegional setting. So basically you want to convert all those different strings into `DATETIME` - correct?

Comment: Some of those dates are ambiguous. Do a data cleanup exercise *first*, to transform all of them into a single (preferably unambiguous) format, [one supported by SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), and *then* put them into a `datetime` column.

Comment: When you get to the end and you've formatted them as best as you can, you can use [ISDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) to only convert the rows which are possible to convert: `CASE WHEN ISDATE(mycolumn) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, mycolumn, <whichever style you've chosen>) ELSE NULL END`

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `nvarchar` column to a `DATETIME`, you will need to use the `CONVERT` function in T-SQL.

This function supports a set of "styles" - [all of which are very well documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

If your source string matches one of those defined styles, you can use the appropriate `CONVERT` to get a `DATETIME` from your string. There is however no "magic" in T-SQL to recognize which conversion style would match your string - that's entirely up to you.

With this query here, you can list out all the `CONVERT` styles for T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT
    Default_100 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 100),
    US_101 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 101),
    ANSI_102 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 102),
    BritishFrench_103 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 103),
    Germany_104 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 104),
    Italian_105 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 105),
    Style106 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 106),
    Style107 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 107),
    Style108 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 108),
    Default_with_ms_109 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 109),
    USA_110 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 110),
    Japan_111 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 111),
    ISO_112 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 112),
    Europe_default_with_ms_113 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 113),
    Style114 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 114),
    ODBC_canonical_120 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 120),
    ODBC_canonical_with_ms_121 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 121),
    ISO_8601_126 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 126),
    ISO_8601_with_timezone_Z_127 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 127),
    Hijri_130 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 130),
    Hijri_131 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Today, 131)
```

If your source string does **not** match any of the predefined styles - you're out of luck, and it'll take a lot more string parsing and T-SQL code to convert your string to a valid `DATETIME`.

If your string matches one of the styles, you can convert it like this:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = CONVERT(DATETIME, '30.04.2012', 104)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to write a function that takes the string and converts it to a non ambiguous date string (yyyy-mm-dd). This can then be converted to a datetime. There's now magical way of converting various formats to date format.